# How to access resources during app testing

Tags: objective-c

Newbie questions.

I am aware that during testing my iPhone app in the Simulator, not all resource files are available in the `[NSBundle mainBundle]`. I understand that the solution is to refer to `[NSBundle bundleForClass:[self class]]` rather than to the mainBundle.

Questions I have:

1. Is refering to `[NSBundle bundleForClass:[self class]]` valid when the app is deployed and is it good practice?
2. Is it good practice to define in the app delegate...

   ```
   NSBundle *appBundle = [NSBundle bundleForClass:[self class]];
   // or, for in final app 
   // NSBundle *appBundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
   ```

... and use `appBundle` throughout the code? Otherwise there are too many places where I refer to `[NSBundle mainBundle]` that I would have to change to the `bundleForClass:[self Class]`.

If I go with this appBundle definition, should I be doing anything else? Perhaps release the appBundle before the app delegate terminates?

Thank you!

Sleiman

Comment: In what cases are you seeing `mainBundle` not work? If it doesn't work in the simualtor then it should never work..

Comment: I'm guessing that you aren't adding the resources to the app bundle and that's why they're not showing up. Any resources in the bundle are in mainBundle. To add or remove resources to a bundle click the little folder at the top-left (folder-view) then click the project at the top then click the target if you have more than one then the tab that says "Copy Bundle Resources." From what you've described I'm guessing that the resource you want in the bundle won't be there.

Comment: @Wain, when running the app in the simulator, not all resources were found in the main bundle.

Comment: @MichaelOlenick, thanks Michael! I looked in that tab and I can see that not all resources listed there. I've added them and now it seems to work.

Comment: Will you please mark the answer correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mainBundle contains everything inside a bundle, the resources for your target (app). XCode tries to add all the assets into the bundle but sometimes misses or other times you may have inadvertently told XCode not to copy it into the bundle. It's important to remember to only put into the bundle what the app needs before release -- if you have test files, remove them -- because they make your app larger which eats up users storage and bandwidth.

To add/remove/inspect what is in the bundle go to the file/group inspector, the little folder icon at the top-left of XCode. Choose the project, the very top-most entry. Select a target if you have more than one. Click Build Phases and scroll down to Copy Bundle Resources. That is where you manage what gets copied into the bundle.